# unknown error: DevToolsActivePort on Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

So this is my initialize code to setup chrome driver using selenium

```py
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-xss-auditor")
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chromeOptions)
```

The problem is i get "unknown error: DevToolsActivePort", which is a very common error that i saw when i tried to search for a solution. None work for me so far.
But when i pull the exact same code from my github into another folder, i run it smoothly, so i want to ask the reason behind that error, does it happen randomly? or something else cause it on my first attempt?

I tried adding `--no-sandbox`, debugging port, to `chromeOptions` but none worked, i also get the latest chromium driver and chrome already.
At least it works for me now by just using the *exact same code* from github, i just curious the cause.

Comment: what's the difference between your code and the github code?